# Computing determinant of nxn matrix without using inbuilt modules

Tags: python, matrix

I'm writing some code which generates a random matrix and then proceeds to find its determinant. This is what I have so far, using the recursive formula for the determinant:

```
import numpy as np
import random

myarray = [] 

myinput=input('Choose a value for N:')
N=int(myinput)

for i in range(N):
    myarray.append([0.0]*N)
for j in range(N):
    for i in range(N):
        myarray[i][j] = random.randint(0,100)


M=np.array(myarray)
print(M)

def det(matrix):
  determinant=0
  a=0
  while a<N:
        M_0a=np.delete(matrix,0,axis=0)
        M_0a=np.delete(M_0a,a,axis=1)
        print(M_0a)
        a+=1
        determinant= determinant + ((-1)**a)*(M[0][a])*det(M_0a)

  return determinant

print(det(M))
```

I've written the function kind of incorrectly as I'm unsure how to proceed. Basically the while loop successively eliminates the rows and columns in the 0th row and ath column, but I guess I need some sort of if statement for the condition that the new matrix is 2x2, thus ending the loop and calculating the base determinant of the 2x2 matrix?
Thanks

Comment: Use a for-loop instead of a while loop. You'll almost always like it more.

Comment: so instead should I put for i in M, for j in i...: and then eliminate the rows and columns that way?